# How to horizontally scroll a stackpanel of n stackpanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I have a horizontal stackpanel that includes many vertical stackpanels.

[image: this image]

The above image shows the stackpanel have 20 items but shows only 12 items to us. The problem is how can we scroll it in horizontal dimension to show all elements?

Comment: You might be looking for a `ScrollViewer`: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFScrollViewer.aspx

Comment: The usual way to produce something like that is to use a listbox or listview. Change the itemspresenter to an orientation horizontal stackpanel. Bind an obseervablecollection of viewmodels to the itemssource. Template out each viewmodel into each item

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `StackPanel` inside a `ScrollViewer` like this:

```xml
<ScrollViewer 
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>Item 1</Label>
        <Label>Item 2</Label>
        <Label>Item 3</Label>
        <Label>Item 4</Label>
        <Label>Item 5</Label>
        <Label>Item 6</Label>
        <Label>Item 7</Label>
        <Label>Item 8</Label>
        <Label>Item 9</Label>
        <Label>Item 10</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i did it but didnt work. my stackpanel have many smaller stackpanels in it. actually it is a stackpanel of many stackpanels. in this condition scrolbar doesnt work

Comment: Which is not particularly obvious from your post and why you should have provided a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @Andy please read question title on top of page. btw, i didnt find any useful answer for my problem yet

Comment: You still haven't provided a minimal reproducible example. No markup. No code.